# Is there a way to list all the installed packages in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I just wanted to see what I have installed so I know what has to be migrated to a next version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings - User` lists all of the packages installed via Package Control.